# Telerik: raddatetimepicker SelectedDateChanged event not work

Tags: xaml, events, telerik, raddatepicker

Hi I use the element  (similar datepicker).
When I change the date using the specific button the event SelectedDateChanged is raised. (correct)
When I change the date writing directly in textbox the event SelectedDateChanged is not raised. (incorrect)

Do you know this problem? and Do you know the solution?

Thanks
(sorry my bad english)

Comment: It should have a LostFocus eventhandler attached to it handling that, has the original control been modified at all I assume?

Answer (score 2):

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDtpTrnDate"
                       runat="server"
                       Calendar-EnableShadows="true"
                       Enabled="false"
                       Culture="en-IN"
                       DateInput-DateFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy"
                       DateInput-EmptyMessage="DD-MMM-YYYY"
                       DateInput-AutoPostBack="true"
                       ShowPopupOnFocus="true"
                       ToolTip="Input Date"
                       AutoPostBack="true"
                       OnSelectedDateChanged="RadDtpTrnDate_SelectedDateChanged">
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

Try this................

Comment: Thanks! The event wasn't firing without autopostback set to true.

Comment: Yes, without setting AutoPostBack = true, an event will not be fired.